# how to bind multiple kendo ui control in one view?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am quite new to MVC so the question may sounds stupid but anyway I need to understand the concept:

In asp.net mvc4, say I have one view, on that page I have one kendo UI control, in this case what I saw from the demos are just make the view strongly typed with the model, like below:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Areas/aspx/Views/Shared/Web.Master"
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.ProductViewModel>>" %>
```

then in page the data bind in this way:

```
<div class="demo-section">
<%: Html.Kendo().ListView<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.ProductViewModel>(Model)
    .Name("listView")
    .TagName("div")
    .ClientTemplateId("template")
    .DataSource(dataSource => {
        dataSource.Read(read => read.Action("Products_Read", "ListView"));
        dataSource.PageSize(15);
    })
    .Pageable()
%>
</div>
```

but what if I have multiple controls and they need different models? then how can I do the data binding? I saw some other demos in this case use the viewbag to pass data from controller to view but is it possible to not use viewbag?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach I have used is to move all of the strongly bound data your view needs into a new class and call it something like ProductPageViewModel.

This new ViewModel would allow you to have as much strongly bound data as you need within your view. Allowing you to avoid having to use ViewBag.

In your Action method you would populate the ProductPageViewModel object instead of the ProductViewModel enumeration.

Take a look below at a sample of how I would structure a new ViewModel:

```
public class ProductPageViewModel
{
  public IEnumerable<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.ProductViewModels> Products { get; set; }
  public List<SelectListItem> SelectList { get; set; }
  public bool IsAdditionalProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Your views declaration would then become:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Areas/aspx/Views/Shared/Web.Master"
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.ProductPageViewModel>" %>
```

Then in your page you can bind this way:

```
<div class="demo-section">
<%: Html.Kendo().ListView<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.ProductViewModel>(Model.Products)
    .Name("listView")
    .TagName("div")
    .ClientTemplateId("template")
    .DataSource(dataSource => {
        dataSource.Read(read => read.Action("Products_Read", "ListView"));
        dataSource.PageSize(15);
    })
    .Pageable()
%>
</div>
<div>
 <%= Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
      .Name("selectList")
      .DataTextField("Text")
      .DataValueField("Value")
      .BindTo(Model.SelectList)
%>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much! this is also what i did after some thinking and your reply give me the confident that i am on the right way.